# Getting PCM Frames from Deezer or Spotify APIs

Tags: signal-processing, spotify, deezer

Is there any way to get PCM frames from a song which is playing in Deezer or Spotify and if there is, could you maybe explain briefly how ?

I checked in the both API a way to do that but I'm not very lucky tonight and I didn't find a answer yet... :(

Any kind of help will be very usefull, thanks a lot.

Kind Regards,

Sébastien.

Comment: I don't know why but stackoverflow will not print the first line of my post which was "Hi all" sorry...

Comment: It's because stackoverflow isn't a forum or a mailing list. You don't need to greet everybody, thank them for answers, or sign your posts. Just asking the question with clear and concise language is enough. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Spotify*

libspotify delivers raw PCM frames in the `music_delivery` callback, see the [API documentation for more details](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/structsp__session__callbacks.html#a33a31478b8de1882ad7847ad033fbaeb). Actually this is the default delivery mechanism for libspotify, so you don't need to do anything special to get raw PCM, that's the format which the library speaks.

I'm not sure about the Spotify Web Apps platform, I'm not a Javascript guy at all...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so if I understood correctly what you were saying, in the callback I can get the frames from the audio and I will normally be able to compute an FFT on them right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you get a `void*` pointer to frames. The channel count and PCM sample properties are also passed to you in that function.